# Libreoffice calc cell refresh

Tags: refresh, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

In LibreOffice Calc I have a LibreOffice Basic funtion (macro) call in a cell. How can I refresh this cell **automatically** when some other cell has been changed without refreshing the whole sheet ?

Comment: Peh, I disagree. The question was about the macros in Libreoffice. And the question was solved by the macro definitions in the Libreoffice. The VBA was only a language for implementation of the macro. The question was not related to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the macro to "Content changed" Sheet Events which can be found in the pulldown menu by right clicking the sheet tab.

Thank you.